# How to create path based routing to multiple Jenkins servers in AWS?

Tags: jenkins, routes, load-balancing

I have three Jenkins servers on three VMs in AWS and I want to route traffic to those three Jenkins server based on the path i.e.:

(Not real links)
https://myjenkinsservers.com/   (Default Jenkins Server)

https://myjenkinsservers.com/applications-ci

https://myjenkinsservers.com/applications-cd

I have created three target groups and assign each server to it. The setting looks fine and I can access the default Jenkins server but when I tried to access the other two servers it falls back to the default server. Is there any setting in the Jenkins config file that needs to be changed so it won't fall back to the default server?

Anything I write after the https://myjenkinsservers.com/whateveriwritehere will fall back to the default Jenkins server.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.